# React Native iOS simulator "Connect to Metro to Develop Javascript"

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm running a react native app and constantly running into the issue of the app not connecting to the code to do automatic updates.

Things I've tried:

- Reloading main.jsbundle via the following command: `npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios/assets`
- Completely removing node and react native from my computer
- Restarting my computer
- Running on a physical device and running on the simulator
- Cleaning derived data in Xcode

This is the screen on starting up, which offers the advice, "Connect to Metro to develop JavaScript."

[image: Connect to Metro to develop JavaScript.]

From the metro bundler that automatically starts up, I get this message when I type 'r' to reload that says, "React Native: No apps connected."

[image: "No apps connected"]

I'm using 0.61 and always have been.

What else should I try?

**EDIT**

I was able to get it working by restarting my computer (again).

Every once in a while, a restart does the trick, yet most of the time it doesn't work. There still has to be a more reliable way of fixing this.

Comment: try doing cmd +d to open shortcuts in simulator and in change bundle location to your metro running address port number e.g:(127.0.0.1:8090)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue some time before. 
Suddenly the App doesn't work anymore if starting only with XCode. I have to start the metro-bundler via CLI... and if running, I had to use "XCode" to run the App. As the metro-bundler still running in the background, XCode didn't start it's own, and the connection could be established.

I've described my request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54569662/xcode-wrong-path-to-module)... which sounds a bit similar to yours. 
Now I don't have any issues anymore if starting from xcode directly. Maybe this was caused of an upgrade of XCode (my current XCode-Version: 10.3)

Comment: First, I have the same issue except with my connected device. It doesn't occur on the sim. I've tried both manually launching metro from CLI, and also letting Xcode launch it. It made no difference. I've also tried manually configuring the bundler (which I've never had to do before -- ever). Still no success.

Answer (score 16):

Dev menu looks like:

[image]

In my case it could happen after recreating main.jsbundle

1. Open any installed ios simulator.
2. install your app (npm run ios)
3. press `cmd + d` being focused on simulator
4. choose configure bundler

bundler preferences:

[image]

5. bundler address - 127.0.0.1
6. port - 8081

then simulator will reconnect itself

Comment: This solved my issue where after deleting main.jsbundle and created a new one caused my simulator not to render new changes(hot reload). By following your steps above, I was able to resolve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Go to device simulator and shake then configure bundler for example 127.0.0.1:8081

Answer (score 3):

Try this while you have your metro bundler opened,

1-delete app and rerun

2-popup message will appear "this app would like to connect to other app on network" Press OK

3-
shake your iphone
--> configure bundler
-->Reset to default

Answer (score 2):

If the above solutions won't work just make sure that you select the scheme as a debug not release.
**

### How to edit scheme :

**
Xcode 12.4 => Product > scheme > edit scheme > run > info > Build Configuration > select debug.

Comment: This answer sounds solid. Unfortunately, it made no difference for me. Hopefully, it'll help someone, though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having this issue while testing on the phone?
I think you should enable the wifi in same network with computer.

Comment: Good point! I did make sure they were on the same network and no dice. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Disconnecting from VPN resolved the network issue I was encountering.

Answer (score 0):

For me , metro server was not running in the background so I just ran the npm start and reloaded the simulator and changes appears!